# suggester completion Elasticsearch don't work with numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

I try running the suggester completion Elasticsearch with numbers as like this

```
{
"suggest": {
    "completer": {
        "prefix": "64274",
        "completion": {
            "skip_duplicates": true,
            "field": "words-suggester"
        }
    }
},
"_source": false
```

}

But I don't receive any result

Answer (score 1):

the problem was the _mapping configuration because by default the analyzer is setter as simple,
and need to be changed as an analyzer standard

so, what you will need to do it's this:

```
"sample": {
  "properties": {
        "words-suggester": {
            "type":"completion",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        }
  }
}
```